# What is costing so much ram while modeling?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, vertices, constraints

In Blender 3.3.2, AMD 3700x, RTX 3070 using latest studio drivers.

These are my current stats while modeling. [image]

I only have 10 active subdivision modifiers with low settings, 2 active booleans and most of everything I already applied decimation to lower the amount of vertices. Aside from that I have some bones with active constraints and a few reference images but this is how much ram Blender is currently using.[image]

I did some math where I found that 1 vertices is 36 bytes of ram, so 1 MB is worth 27777.7777778 vertices and 1 GB is worth 27777777.7778 vertices. I should hardly be close to 9 GB of ram even if running the program itself costs 2 GB, (guessing) I should only be at 4 GB tops with everything you would think. At one point I was even at 20GB of ram back when I was at 15 million vertices. This worries me because I potentially want moving scenes that could cost 100 million to maybe 500 million vertices which theoretically should be possible with my 64gb of ram, 64 gb would be equal to 1.77 billion vertices. Are there things that could be causing this or will blender adjust accordingly?
I should also add that every time I open this project the ram sky rockets while it freezes momentarily and I have no idea why.

Comment: The cost of a vertex depends on its data: location, definitely; but also weights, UV, custom normals....  Topo also costs, Blender needs to know edges connect and what materials are assigned to faces.  I expect both pre- and post- modified geometry need to be stored in RAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds reasonable that in order to process data you might need more memory than to just store it. If you have armatures for dense geometry, weights need to be stored as well, so that sounds like some considerable amount of data since every bone needs to store weights for every vertex it effects if I understand it correctly. I doubt that if you need scenes that dense, you are not going to use any textures, so it seems you will definitely need more RAM.

On the other hand 100 000 000 - 500 000 000 verts does not sound reasonable amount of geometry for a single scene. You should probably consider looking for more efficient ways to achieve results that you need. This is unusual. Usual 4K screen has only 8 294 400 pixels, 8K - 33 177 600 pixels. Do you really need more vertices than you have pixels? That sounds a bit wrong. Obviously, I have no idea, what you are working on, so I don't know, but it seems a bit unusual. It makes sense to reevaluate the situation.